# Getting Helper Data php in magento

Tags: magento, math, php, adminhtml

Have been trying to get a variable percentage from two helper functions inside .phtml file in magento

basically i have two variables based on two helper functions that on their own output/echo static numbers. Problem is in the below php they are just displaying as the value and not dividing/multiplying. So like i said the helper data & module work is using the data as variables to do/complete the equation within the .phtml file. See code below

`get->FunctionA()` just equals a round number value (from a collection)

`get->FunctionB()` just equals a round number value as well (from a collection)

probs not the best way but this just outputs two values from helper data and not dividing.

```
echo Mage::helper('module/data')->getFunctionA() / Mage::helper('module/data')->getFunctionB();
```

Also this does not work either, just produces the same result and is probs the best/easiest way

```
$dataA = Mage::helper('module/data')->getFunctionA(); 
$dataB = Mage::helper('module/data')->getFunctionB();
$result = ($dataA / $dataB) * 100;
echo $result;
```

Like i said above the values can be echoed (in either helper function or phtml files but the actual calculation does not wont to work

Any help would be great

Comment: What does getFunctionA and getFunctionB will return ?

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorted the problem out. What was happening was that in the helper file the getFunctionA() & getFunctionB() value was being echoed when i should have been just returning the value then echoing the helper function in the .phtml file. Doh! See below the helper function example that is now working Woohoo!!!

```
public function getFunctionA()
{
$FunctionA = Mage::getModel('module/collection')->getCollection();
$FunctionA->addFieldToFilter('attribute', 'value_to_filter');
$FunctionA->addFieldToFilter('status','1');
return ''.count($FunctionA) . ''; //this line was the problem cause i was echoing & not returning the value

}
```

Now the value can be echoed in the phtml & the math equation is confirmed working

```
$dataA = Mage::helper('module/data')->getFunctionA(); 
$dataB = Mage::helper('module/core')->getFunctionB();
$result = ($dataA / $dataB) * 100;
echo $result;
```

this code does the math and now i can rest.